# How to manually constructing a dynamic link to BiqQuery cloud console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'd like to create a dynamic link to the `BigQuery cloud console`.

The link should load a simple query in the cloud console for a given table and then the user can click run to see a result for such query.

I tried this:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=PROJECT_NAME&p=PROJECT_NAME&d=DATA_SET&t=TABLE_NAME&page=table
```

But it only shows the scheme of the given table.

Also, I noticed that I can use `page=queryresults` but this change nothing.

Is it possible to pass somehow an encoded `SQL query` by the URL?

Comment: Would the functionality of ["Saved queries"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/saving-sharing-queries) in the BigQuery console satisfy your requirements? It is about preparing the query in advance, saving it, and then getting the link to this saved query. It is not directly encoding the query in the URL, but rather sharing the URL of the existing query

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It sounds fine. also, there is an option `to share saved queries by the URL`. but to be fully happy I would need to create a saved query by API but I think this is not possible.